# RegEx: Match odd amount of repeat between other characters in each line

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I was wondering how to match and replace an odd amount of slashes (`\`) in every line at javascript.
They are used in escaping a string, but sometimes the string is wrapped into lines, so the slash have to move to the next line.

Here is an example: http://regex101.com/r/iI9vO9

I want to match the lines which are marked via "Yes" and ignore the lines marked with "No".

For Example:

```
"Yes 1\" + 
"No 2\\" + 
"Yes 3\\\" + 
"No 4\\\\" + 
"No"
```

Should be changed to:

```
"Yes 1" + 
"\No 2\\" + 
"Yes 3\\" + 
"\No 4\\\\" + 
"No"
```

Notice there is characters before and after the slashes in each line, and the slash is moved to the next line when it is repeated an odd time.
I couldn't get it working with `(\\)(\\\\)*` or look-around.

This is what I have in mind if this work:

```
text.replace(/([^\\])\\" \+ \n"(.)/gm, '$1\\$2"+ \n "')
```

If this is not possible with RegEx, I would appreciate any other way to make this possible.
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
For whoever look this up on Google, this is exactly what solves the problem:

```
text.replace(/([^\\])((\\{2})*)\\" \+ \n"/g, '$1$2" + \n"\\')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mGWF/1/

Comment: I just made a simple one. Check it out: http://regex101.com/r/fH9iS5

Comment: Updated: http://regex101.com/r/tN7fW4

Comment: good outside the box thinking there sshashank

Comment: @Martin, Thank you. Could you please make a full fledged answer out of that? Thank you.

Comment: Nice, but please notice it need to match the odd slashes. Neither of the RegExes you provided worked on this! Also please use JavaScript as the RegEx engine. Thanks!

Comment: @David I think the question could use a bit of clarification... the regex that sshashank124 provided demonstrates how you can do a match on an odd number of characters so it should be easy to modify to match to an odd number of slashes which I believe is what your question was in the first place: "I was wondering how to match and replace an odd amount of slashes (\) in javascript." I would consider that an answer - if not, please modify your question as it is somewhat unclear. Warning: I have not yet had my morning coffee yet so your question may be clear, but my head may just be foggy ;)

Comment: @Martin Yeah sorry, I clarified my question more (though I thought the example would say what I mean.) Can you just provide some RegEx that would work on my example? Take a look at this: hivelogic.com/enkoder

Comment: @sshashank nice work! I dont understand how \3 works in this situation? Ive never saw this before, but after googling it means the third matched group? How would this work with one object in brackets? Edit: I was struggling to understand why you could just use {3}, but this ensures it is the same object! Nvm I got it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
text = text.replace(/([^\\])((\\{2})*)\\\n/g, "$1$2\n\\")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mGWF/

Comment: Yeah somehow, but would you please include `" \n + "` in your jsfiddle? I'm trying to use it but it removes all the even slashes...

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks! I'm editing this answer